# Jenkins 2.82 and Blue Ocean plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, jenkins-blueocean

I have latest Jenkins instance (version 2.82)

[image]
It's up and running.

Now, https://jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/getting-started/ 
I'm trying to install **Blue Ocean Plugin**, but it's **NOT** visible under `Available` or `Installed` tabs under `Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins` while all other plugins are showing up fine.

Per the following link, it says it can be installed for Jenkins > 2.7.1:

```
Blue Ocean is available from the Jenkins update center for Jenkins 2.7.1 and above.
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin

Anybody else having the same issue with this or recent versions?

Comment: Installed a fresh Jenkins ver. 2.82. And the plugin is listed below External Site/Tool Integrations

Comment: @mszalbach where's this External Site/Tool Integrations? you mean in Jenkins global configuration Manage Jenkins > here or under Manage Plugins? I didn't find it in these 2 locations, please include a snapshot of image if possible.

Comment: It is located under JENKINS_URL/pluginManager/available. Screenshot from old jenkins with warning:https://imgur.com/a/h2Kmz.

Comment: Under available tab, if you type Blue or Ocean in the search box, are you seeing no rows or is it still showing Blue Ocean listed there?

Comment: Still showing Blue Ocean plugin, when using the Jenkins search filed in Jenkins 2.60.3 and 2.73.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check manage plugin if there are any dependent plugins requires upgrade.  "Open BlueOcean" link should be on the left menu of your Jenkins dashboard...